# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie mocking using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq

Hi i'm doing some unit test on my ASP.Net MVC2 project. I'm using Moq framework. In my LogOnController,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl = "")
{
  FormsAuthenticationService FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService();
  FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

 }
```

In FormAuthenticationService class,

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
    {
        public virtual void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot     be null or empty.", "userName");
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
        }
        public void SignOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
    }
```

My problem is how can i avoid executing

```
FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

this line. Or is there any way to Moq

```
 FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

using Moq framework **without** changing my ASP.Net MVC2 project.

Comment: What is the SUT (System Under Test) - `LogOnController` or `FormsAuthenticationService`? If it's the former, a fake should be supplied for the `FormsAuthenticationService` and you should verify that the `SignIn` method is called on it. The latter is harder to unit test as it requires a current `HttpContext` to which to add a cookie (to the `HttpResponse`).

Comment: I want to test LogOnController. I tried to mock FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe); 
in this way,
var formService=new Mock<FormsAuthenticationService>();
But formservice.SignIn does not return anything. How can I avoid executing that line or how to mock that line. I have no idea how to Mock that using Moq.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inject `IFormsAuthenticationService` as a dependency to your `LogOnController` like this

```
private IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthenticationService;
public LogOnController() : this(new FormsAuthenticationService())
{
}

public LogOnController(IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthenticationService) : this(new FormsAuthenticationService())
{
    this.formsAuthenticationService = formsAuthenticationService;
}
```

The first constructor is for the framework so that the correct instance of `IFormsAuthenticationService` is used at runtime.

Now in your tests create an instance of `LogonController` using the other constructor by passing mock as below

```
var mockformsAuthenticationService = new Mock<IFormsAuthenticationService>();
//Setup your mock here
```

Change your action code to use the private field `formsAuthenticationService` as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    formsAuthenticationService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
}
```

Hope this helps. I have left out the mock setup for you. Let me know if you are not sure how to set that up.

Comment: Thanks Suhas. I have no idea where to put this code since I'm new to ASP.Net u=Unit testing. Did you mean I should change my LogOnController  in the mvc project? Please be kind enough to explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope it's clear to you now. Let me know if you still face issues with this.

Comment: I followed the given steps.Some errors came and i could manage that.It works.Really appreciative your kindness. Thank you.