# Error in UnitTest for WebSecurity.Login simple membership

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am writing a unit test for login process and have used simple membership api.
from web project, login is working fine, but while in unit test. simple membership api is raising exception.

API is throwing error on WebSecurity.Login method.

> System.NullReferenceException was caught
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     Source=System.Web
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie, String strCookiePath)
>          at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistCookie)
>          at [ code ]
>     InnerException:

WebSecurity.UserExists is working fine.

I think, error is due to 'cookies object is not available in unit test project'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acually [WebSecurity.Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) uses [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) behind the scene,
since FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie uses old httpcontext api therefore even with [moq httpcontext](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/mocking-httpcontext-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-unittests-using-moq/) it is throwing exception.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1871234.aspx

so solution is to dependency injection.

[FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie mocking using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395813/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-mocking-using-moq)

http://forums.asp.net/post/5257516.aspx