# unit testing login Api controller with form authentication

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I am writing unit test case for Web API application. where I have login API controller. Login controller use Form authentication.

```
_tokenServices = (ITokenServices)_unityResolver.GetService(typeof(ITokenServices)); 

AccountsApiController accountsApiController = new 
AccountsApiController(_tokenServices);

LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser();

loginUser.UserName = "sampluser";

loginUser.Password = "samplePassword";

controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();

controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

accountsApiController.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext();

HttpResponseMessage accountApiControllerResponse = accountsApiController.Login(loginUser);

Assert.IsTrue(accountApiControllerResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

If i run the unit test case i am getting null exception in the following line

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginUser.UserName,
>   createPersistentCookie: false);

Comment: please include the full test method with method declaration and the method under test.  Quick thought.  Don't use any IoC in a unit test.  If you need an external service, mock that out.  so ITokenServices mocked out using Moq or FakeitEasy.  Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395813/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-mocking-using-moq